# Разница в безопасности мобильного интернета и интернета через вай-фай

Tags: безопасность

Вчера пришла СМС от левого номера:

> "Привет, посмотри клевые видосы %ссылка%".

Скорее всего мошенник. На сайте написано, что работает только на мобильно интернете. Я не стал заходить на него с моб.интернета.

Есть ли разница в безопасности моб.интернета и обычного? то сталкивался с такой схемой?

Comment: Может, на сайте эксплоиты только под мобильный браузер :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конечно есть. Некоторые провайдеры имеют "особенности", которые позволяют мошенникам узнать номер мобильного телефона. А в некоторых случаях даже незаметно подписать на какую-нибудь платную услугу (например, описано тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/196894/).

Я специально написал "особенности", потому что в одних случаях это реальные уязвимости, а в некоторых похоже договоренности с оператором связи, выдаваемое как "забота о пользователе".

С другой стороны, домашний вайфай также не всегда безопасный. Есть упоминания о уязвимостях, которые позволяют взаимодействовать с роутером (Вы открываете страницу в браузере, а она уже хитрым способом стучиться на роутер. Адрес роутера обычно известный и там обычно залогинен.) и прописать там своих настроек (например, кастомный dns).

**UPD**

Вспоминил, ещё есть сайты, при заходе на которые, предлагает обновить flash плеер или версию андроида. И так ненавязчиво предалгают прокликать по кнопкам. Многие на это ведуться. В результате устанавливают на свой телефон зловреда, а что он будет делать... а кто его знает.

Comment: а ничего, что я с браузера зашел. То есть дал им возможно узнать мой IP. Зная мой IP и номер телефона, что они могут сделать?

Comment: врядли что то будут делать. Но в статистику запишут. Иногда такая статистика может стоить очень дорого. Когда то было такое "вычислю по айпи". Теперь похоже обратый процесс - присылаем смс, человек заходит, узнаем его айпи:)

Comment: "дорого стоить" - например? И у меня динамический IP

Comment: Суммы я не скажу - я подобным не занимаюсь. Но вот к примеру, допустим, что  есть большая база, где храниться соответствие ip-номер. по ip можно определить координаты, иногда достаточно точно.А теперь представьте, кто то наваял на форуме свежий коментарий и радостно потирает ручки. А через пару минут ему звонят на мобильный...

Comment: а если у меня динамический айпишник?
И еще один вопрос: вот на сайт провайдера, в личный кабинет я могу заходить вообще без паролей. Я так понимаю просто по айпи. Можно ли зайти на мой провайдер подделав айпи?

Comment: По динамическому айпи можно определить провайдера. А это также полезная информация.

А раз можно зайти в личный кабинет без пароля, значит теоретически, можно сделать фрейм, который "сможет также зайти" пока Вы будете просматривать зловредный сайт. А что можно сделать зайдя в личный кабинет.... это уже отдельный вопрос. У некоторых там реальные паспортные данные к примеру.